# Keeping MacBook Pro on Sleep Mode for days

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, battery

I usually use my MacBook Pro for programming purposes and is mostly open about 14 hours a day, with 2-3 hours being plugged in until the charging is complete and then I disconnect from power afterwards to cycle the battery. When I leave for home, I just put the machine on Sleep Mode by closing the lid and not actually shutting it down. I only shut it down every Friday for the weekend.

Will this harm my MacBook Pro in some way? Will the battery life get reduced if this is done? It is also connected to Wi-Fi the whole week, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty close to my typical MacBook Air usage. Luckily, it seems that we're on track:

> For proper maintenance of a lithium-based battery, it’s important to keep the electrons in it moving occasionally. Apple does not recommend leaving your portable plugged in all the time. An ideal use would be a commuter who uses her notebook on the train, then plugs it in at the office to charge. This keeps the battery juices flowing.

See Apple's page on laptop batteries for lots more information: [apple.com](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html)

Keep in mind that MacBook batteries are estimated to live through around 1000 charge-discharge cycles before their max capacity drops to 80% (same source). Try to approximate the ideal scenario Apple describes, and avoid running the battery to near-zero between every charge.

Comment: I usually recharge when the battery drops to around 12% so I think I'm on the safe road. But what if keep it sleeping on Friday (unplugged from power source) over the weekend and wake it up only on Monday?

Comment: By running it down that far you are using up those cycles: you are using 0.88 cycles each day. If you recharge at 60% or 70% you are only using 0.3 or 0.4 cycles per day.

Comment: @LanceGray Seems like Apple recommends a full cycle (or an equivalent number of partial cycles) at least once a month. As long as you're doing that, you should be fine. If you're worried, you can use the "Schedule…" button in the Energy Saver prefs to automatically shut down for the weekend.